# I got this error in for 3 loop using python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I don't know how to resolve this.. i searched everywhere but i don't found something..

i got this error

```
File "D:/python project/master_an1/frontend.py", line 176, in top3_grouped
    for row3 in database.selecttopstudents(row,row2):
  File "D:\python project\master_an1\backend.py", line 64, in selecttopstudents
    self.cur.execute("SELECT nume,prenume,media FROM student WHERE an=? AND facultate=? ORDER BY media LIMIT 3", (faculty,year))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

And i have this code..

```
def top3_grouped(self):
    self.list2.delete(0, END)
    for row in database.selectfaculty():
        self.list2.insert(END, row)
        for row2 in database.selectyear(row):
            self.list2.insert(END, row2)
            for row3 in database.selecttopstudents(row,row2):
                self.list2.insert(END, row3)

def selectfaculty(self):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT facultate FROM student GROUP BY facultate")
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def selectyear(self,faculty):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT an FROM student WHERE facultate=? GROUP BY an", faculty)
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def selecttopstudents(self, faculty,year):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT nume,prenume,media FROM student WHERE facultate=? AND an=? ORDER BY media LIMIT 3", (faculty,year))
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return rows
```

if I delete the third for (row3) works perfectly only with two parameters get this error why? Year is INTEGER and faculty is TEXT

When i run the aplication i have this, display first words.. 
[click see image from imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGIz2.png)

Comment: I think you have the order of parameters reversed, should be `(year, faculty)`

Comment: @TomNash i tried right now but same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Year is INTEGER and faculty is TEXT

You're passing `row` and `row2` as the arguments to `selecttopstudents()`, and those items are not text and integer.

Those values came from `selectfaculty()` and `selectyear()`, which you haven't shown us, but presumably they are entire rows from a table.

You can't pass an entire row object to a function that expects only a single column value.

You need to extract only the faculty and year values from those rows, and use those -- perhaps something like this?

```
for row3 in database.selecttopstudents(row['faculty'], row2['year']):
```

Comment: i have edited the post, and i put the selectfaculty() and selectyear() function 
If i use your sintax i got this error
for row3 in database.selecttopstudents(row['facultate'],row2['an']):
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: OMG works like that
for row3 in database.selecttopstudents(row[0], row2[0]): i use index not str